# What does $x=\sum 2^{8(n-i)}x_i$ mean in words?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble understanding the equation

> $x=\sum 2^{8(n-i)}x_i$

What is the point of the sum symbol? What does it change bout the equation? Is it necessary?

EDIT: There is more to the overall question I have trouble understanding:

> Let $x1, x2,…, xn$ be the base-256 encoding of x satisfying:
>   $x =\sum2^{8(n-i)}
> x_i$, for $i = 1$ to n.

Comment: Assuming that the index goes from $i=0$ to $i=n$, you get that $x=2^{8n}x_0+ 2^{8(n-1)}x_1+\cdots+2^8 x_{n-1}+x_n$.

Comment: What do you mean, the index?

Comment: The correct way to write the summation is with lower and upper limits: $x=\sum _{i=0} ^n 2^{8(n-i)}x_i$. The $i$-th term would be $2^{8(n-i)}x_i$ and we are adding them for $i=0$ until $i=n$. $i$ is called the index of the sum, and in some cases it is not written in the lower and upper limits because the author takes it for granted (but it is not a good practice). So the sum happens to be what I wrote in the comment above. If you drop the sum, you only have one term, not a sum of $n$ terms, so it would not be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is the formal mathematical way of stating that $x$ is an $n$ byte unsigned integer with the bytes numbered from $x_1$ to $x_n$ from MSB to LSB in big-endian order. The index $i$ goes from $1$ to $n$ in the summation notation.

Answer (score 0):

The summation implies the quantity is a sum of discrete elements. This may represent a discrete time signal that decays as 'i' increases. 'n' could be considered a constant.

Answer (score 0):

A number written in base $256$ is $\displaystyle \sum_0^n 256^i x_i$ where the $x_i$ are the individual digits. This can be written $\displaystyle \sum_0^n 2^{8i} x_i$. If you reverse the digits it becomes $\displaystyle \sum_0^n 2^{8(n-i)} x_i$ which is your expression.

So it is a representation of a number written in base 256 with its digits in reverse order.